# Is there a detached apposition?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Like his fellow genius, Tolkien, C.S. Lewis has redefined the nature of fantasy.

After describing the ellipsis and detached apposition to exclude fronting:

> A real Tolkien, C.S. Lewis is, **like his fellow genius was doing it**, has redefined the nature of fantasy.

Is the bold part called a detached apposition?

Comment: Your "rephrasing" is syntactic gibberish. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Terminology isn't my specialist subject, but I think what you're talking about here might be more often referred to as [***Close** and **Loose**
Apposition*.](http://web.khu.ac.kr/~jongbok/research/2014/2014-dom-apposition.pdf)

Comment: Your rewrite of the sentence doesn't make sense. It's nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [*A Student's’ Guide to English Syntax: from Word to Discourse...*](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/A_Student_s_Guide_to_English_Syntax_from/FsyaEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22detached%20apposition%22&pg=PA57&printsec=frontcover)

An **apposition** is a special kind of an attribute expressed by a noun (with or without accompanying words) which characterizes or explains the word modified by giving the person or thing another name. There are two kinds of apposition - the **close apposition** and the **loose** or **detached apposition.**

A **close apposition** is not separated by commas, and stands in close connection with the word modified. These word-groups generally consist either of the name of a person and a noun denoting relationship, or a geographical name and some common noun, e.g. ***Professor Brown, President Roosevelt, Aunt Polly,*** etc.

A **loose** or **detached apposition** is not so closely connected with the noun. It is always separated by commas and has a stress of its own. e.g. ***Big and strong**, he impressed us greatly. My brother, **a five-year-old boy**, doesn't go to school yet.*

---

After the second comma, OP's rephrased text is syntactic garbage, but given the above definitions it should be obvious that initial ***A real Tolkien*** is in "loose apposition" to its referent *(**C.S. Lewis**)*.

Note that the original text uses a ***simile*** (Lewis is ***like*** Tolkien), but the revised version "promotes" that to a ***metaphor*** (Lewis ***is*** "a Tolkien").